# How do i use two 2 dimentional arrays to form a 3 dimentional one without using loops in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let A and B be two numpy arrays with shapes ( X , Y ) and ( Z , Y ) respectively. I need an array C with shape ( X , Y , Z) where, for every x , y and z, C[ x , y , z ] = A[ x , y ] - B[ z , y ].

The fastest way i know to compute C is to subtract B from every row of A, like in this sample of code.

```
import numpy

X , Y , Z = 10 , 8 , 3

A = numpy.random.rand( ( X , Y ) )
B = numpy.random.rand( ( Z , Y ) )
C = numpy.zeros( ( X , Y , Z ) )

for x in range( X ):
    C[ x ] = A[ x ] - B

print( A , B , C , sep = "\n\n")
```

Is there any vectorized way to do this without needing to use loop, so the code could run faster?

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Use `A[..., None] - B.T`

Answer (score 0):

This is called broadcasting, with `B` transformed:

```
C = A[:,:,None] - B.T[None,:,:]

C.shape
```

Output

```
(10, 8, 3)
```